# How to seperate a list column to multiple logical columns in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data like that looks like the following:
[image]

```
dput(head(my.data[c("name", "categories")],1))

structure(list(name = "among us", categories = list(c("OnlinePvPLAN", 
"PvPOnlineCo-opLAN", "Co-opCross-PlatformMultiplayerRemote", 
"Playon", "PhoneRemotePlay", "onTablet]"))), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

As you can imagine this structure is not easy to deal with. I want to separate the `categories` column to multiple logical columns like the following:

```
name | OnlinePvPLAN | PvPOnlineCo-opLAN | MMOOnlinePvPOnline
-----|--------------|-------------------|--------------------     .....
among|    TRUE      |        TRUE       |       FALSE
us
```

Since there are there are lot's of category columns I decided to write a function to write function that takes a list of categories to separate.

With the following code I can find columns that are in a particular category:

```r
filter(my.data, map_lgl(my.data$categories, ~"OnlinePvPLAN" %in% .))
```

Using this, I wrote the following function:

```r
compile.category.func <- function(data, category.list){
  lapply(X=category.list, function(category){
    category <- c(category)
    mutate(data, category=ifelse(map_lgl(data$categories, ~category %in% .), TRUE, FALSE))
  })
  data
}
output <- compile.category.func(my.data, c("OnlinePvPLAN","MMOOnlinePvPOnline"))
```

However this function doesn't work and doesn't generate any new columns.

Comment: I am not sure about the correct structure.  Perhaps `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);df1 %>% unnest(categories) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = categories, values_from = categories, values_fn = list(categories = function(x) length(x) > 0), values_fill = TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun added the `dput` output

Comment: Thanks.  Can you try the code. `my.data %>% unnest(categories) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = categories, values_from = categories, values_fn = list(categories = function(x) length(x) > 0), values_fill = TRUE)`, it seems to work for me

Comment: @akrun Tried your code. Columns are generated but they are all set as TRUE.

Comment: Your dput had only one row.  Suppose there are multiple rows, if some of the row values after the `unnest` are not present, it wil be FALSE

Comment: what I meant is that `MMOOnlinePvPOnline` is not found in the first row, and if it is present in second row, it will become FALSE for first row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unnest into long form, use table to create the frequencies, use mutate to convert to TRUE/FALSE, then as.data.frame.matrix to convert that to a data frame and finally add the name column back.  Omit the mutate line if 1/0 is wanted instead.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

DF %>%     
  unnest_longer(categories) %>% 
  table %>% 
  as.data.frame.matrix %>%
  mutate(across(, as.logical)) %>%
  rownames_to_column("name")
```

giving

```
      name Co-opCross-PlatformMultiplayerRemote OnlinePvPLAN onTablet]
1 among us                                 TRUE         TRUE      TRUE
  PhoneRemotePlay Playon PvPOnlineCo-opLAN
1            TRUE   TRUE              TRUE
```

Comment: This works really well. Is it possible to dynamically determine the which columns will be generated via a function?

Comment: To only have some columns use a filter statement after the unnest_longer or join it to a data frame containing a column with the desired names or  use a select statement at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works as intended.